# Spring datasource connection pool timeout

Tags: spring, datasource, connection-pooling

I have a Spring application which works fine but after a prolonged period of inactivity on the application (overnight) when accessed it in the morning it fails to connect to the db. 
It is definitely seems to be related with sql server timing out.

I have added some changes to the connection pooling properties also included validation query, then re-build application and deployed them.
It did not solve the problem; the connection works until the next morning and throws the same error again.

My Concerns:

1. I am using spring profile for different environment. Could this be an issue.
2. Is there any configuration in the sql server which I might not be aware off.

Technology Stack:

```
Apache-Tomcat 7.0.53
MS SQL Server 2012  
java-version 1.7
spring.framework.version 4.0.2.RELEASE
hibernate-core 4.3.4.Final
hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.4.Final
jtds 1.3.1
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="PACKAGE_NAME"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryXXX"
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManagerXXX" />

<bean id="dataSourceXXX" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${XXX.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${XXX.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${XXX.jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="30000" /> <!-- (30 secs which is the default value) -->
    <property name="maxIdle" value="15" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="validationInterval" value="30000" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="120" />
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="suspectTimeout" value="90" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="120000" />    
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />   
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />   
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />  
    <property name="jdbcInterceptors" value="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer" /> 
</bean>

<!-- XXX JPA Entity Manager Factory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryXXX" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitXXX"/> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceXXX"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- XXX Transaction Manager Factory -->    
<bean id="transactionManagerXXX" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryXXX" />
    <qualifier value="XXX"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerXXX" />
<!-- End XXX -->
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:430)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.createMetsFiles(Unknown Source)
    ......
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.executeSQL(TdsCore.java:1093)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.submitSQL(TdsCore.java:938)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.setAutoCommit(JtdsConnection.java:2312)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:850)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try after disabling the Tomcat HTTP monitor.
The steps to disable monitor are:
 Tools --> Server --> Choose the server --> Toggle Enable HTTP Monitor

Comment: We run the spring application under Tomcat webserver and we havent got anything like Tomcat HTTP monitor.

Comment: Check the OS settings where SQL server is running.Its detecting in activity at Port and closing.